# How do I create a component in Angular 2 that imports the QuillJS module?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, quill

I am fairly new to Angular 2 and TypeScript. I am using AngularCLI and NPM to create my Angular Project. I have used NPM to install the quill node module into my project. I am now trying to create a component in which  I can customize my quill editor through their API.

I am trying to use:

```
import * as Quill from 'quill';
```

This is returning a 'cannot find quill module' error.

I have already added

```
"": "0.0.26",
"quill": "^1.0.4",
```

to package.json as dependencies.

Comment: Try `import * as quill from 'quill'; ` instead. There might be case issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue in a pet Angular CLI project generated with the `ng new` command, and it worked fine. Here is the code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Quill from 'quill';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(Quill);
  }
}
```

And here's the output I get:
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a7mn.png)

Go to you project's `node_modules` folder and look for a folder named `quill`, anyway, even if it is there, delete the `node_modules` folder and  run `npm i` command again

Comment: deleting node_modules and running npm i worked! thank you!