# How do I include JavaScript Modules into my Angular-Cli App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, quill

I have downloaded the open source library [QuillJS](https://github.com/quilljs/quill) as a stand alone project.  I have added that folder containing Quill into my Angular Cli app. Based on the Quill Docs, I believe I need to include Quill.js in my scripts for Angular Cli to be able to use the library.

However, Quill uses JavaScript Modules, which I have pulled right from their Git Hub and when my Angular app runs Quill.js errors out with this error:

[image: Quill Import Error]

I know the reference is accurate, but I don't think Angular knows how to handle the references.  I am trying to edit the open source code of Quill locally and test my changes, but I can not get my app to compile correctly.  What I am missing here?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. add the script to your index.html file
2. Add it in the .angular-cli.json file in `apps:[ "scripts: [] ]`
   for example:

   apps: [
       "scripts": [
           "./Quill/Quill.js"
       ]
   ]

Comment: Currently, I have the reference in my .angular-cli.json but I have tried both and have gotten the same error in either case :(

Comment: I use ngx-quill-editor@latest (to install: npm install ngx-quill-editor --save) not Quill.js directly

Comment: @Eliseo Yeah, the problem is I am tasked with updating the actual Source Code with one of the backlogged items in Quill's Icebox, so I need to use the library itself rather than an NPM install

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149376/how-do-i-create-a-component-in-angular-2-that-imports-the-quilljs-module

Comment: @Eliseo right, that is if I want to use the Nuget Package, I have the library downloaded locally and I want to reference the library without Nuget